# How to make the full-screen button work after switching the url?

Tags: r, http, https, shiny

Currently, we are using the Professional Plan (Monthly) which give us the ability to deploy the website to our own url. I follow the following documentation provided on the shiny official website

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/custom-domains.html

After following this tutorial, we met one problem. The 'full-screen' button for the leaflet map will not longer work because we get a error like this:

`Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image '<URL>'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`

Are there some possible solutions for this? Note: We are setting the CNAME using the [blue host] and deploy the application to the shiny web server.

Comment: Have you tried the [shinyapps mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users) or the [Rstudio support site](http://support.rstudio.com/)? Those will probably get you to the right people to have your question answered.

Comment: Thank for your advise, I have also posted one site there.

Comment: Try opening the chrome inspector to find out which content actually gets loaded over HTTP